# Java palindrome

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

i have beginner question in java, as i don't know what is wrong with my array, because i just can't index through them. yes i know there is another faster way to check palindrome but pls take a look.

```
public boolean palindrom (String a){
    List<String> normal = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> modified = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String x: a.split("")){
        normal.add(x);
    }

    for (String x:new StringBuilder(a).reverse().toString().split("")){
        modified.add(x);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<a.split("").length;i++){
        if (normal[i]!=modified[i]){
          //in this line above is error as it doesnt recognise "normal" and "modified" arrays
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: What do you mean by *can't index through them*? What is the issue exactly?

Comment: `normal` and `modified` are `List` and not `Array`, you cannot reference like `normal[i]`. You need to do `normal.get(i)`.

Comment: the error i get is The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<String>. i believe array is not defined right

Comment: You should add error information to your question so others wouldn't need to search for them in comments. Use [edit] option for that.

Comment: Also to prevent your next question read: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not Arrays but `ArrayList`
To get element `i` you have to do `normal.get(i)`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: thank you! that did it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lists aren't indexed in the same way arrays are. Rather than use normal[i], you would use normal.get(i).

```
for (int i=0;i<a.split("").length;i++){
    if (normal.get(i) != modified.get(i)){
        return false;
    }
}
```